# How to store html control id's in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i have generated multiple html control dynamically in asp.net, each has unique id. I wanted to store the all element id's in JavaScript array in the same page.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please provide your current code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pattern search in JavaScript on any event.